# Scoped style doesn't work in prod mode <style scoped src="..." />

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue 2.6.14

I wrote the following in my Single File component:

```html
<style scoped src="@/common/assets/landing/Land.css" />
```

in order to include a pre-existing file.

Because I want the style to apply to this component only, I used this `scoped` attribute.

It works perfectly when I run my app with `vue-cli-service serve` and when I compile in `dev` mode with `vue-cli-service build --mode=preprod`.

However, as soon as I compile in prod mode with `vue-cli-service build`, it doesn't work anymore as intended: the style apply globally on all pages of the application.

I can't find anyone having the issue on the Internet.
Can someone help me?

Because compilation is working as intended in dev mode but not in prod mode, I think it should be a bug in the compiler.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I would like to help you but need to know in which relation your component stands to the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

### Try it

```html
<style scoped>
  @import '~@/common/assets/landing/Land.css';
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually: it appeared that every random CSS file located in the `@/common/assets/` is included globally by the production builder.

It makes no sense at all to me, I believe it's a bug of the compiler.

Whatever it closes the issue.